# Parsing html files using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have several Html files stored in the same directory (TestReport1.html, TestReport2.html....) with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <section class='summary'>
        <ul class='resultSummary'>
          <li class='Passed'>
            <div class='summaryLine'>
              <div class='summaryLabel'>Passed</div>
              <span class='summaryCount'>199</span>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' class='cbx_toggle' unchecked/>
          </li>
          <li class='Inconclusive'>
            <div class='summaryLine'>
              <div class='summaryLabel'>Inconclusive</div>
              <span class='summaryCount'>10</span>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' class='cbx_toggle' unchecked/>
          </li>
          <li class='NotImplemented'>
            <div class='summaryLine'>
              <div class='summaryLabel'>Not Implemented</div>
              <span class='summaryCount'>5</span>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' class='cbx_toggle' unchecked/>
          </li>
          <li class='Failed'>
            <div class='summaryLine'>
              <div class='summaryLabel'>Failed</div>
              <span class='summaryCount'>12</span>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' class='cbx_toggle' checked/>
          </li>
          <li id='summaryChart'</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to parse each html file and get the values from each node list and its related stored value into an output something like that:

TestReport1:
Passed: 199
Inconclusive:10
Not Implemented: 5
Failed: 12

TestReport2:
Passed: 20
Inconclusive:10
Not Implemented: 50
Failed: 120

Then I want to merge all the results into a single html summary file :

SummaryTestReport:
Total Passed: 199
Total Inconclusive:10
Total Not Implemented: 5
Total Failed: 12

Any hints and ides would be more than appreciated

Comment: Your question seems to be too broad. Which part of your program do you have problem with (enumerating html files, parsing html, reading values from nodes, etc)? Also your question should include relevant parts of code you have written so far (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) - don't expect us to write the whole program for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Description: HAP - Load (From File)
// Website: https://html-agility-pack.net/
// Run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EsvZyg

// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack

using System;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SaveHtmlFile();

        #region example

        var path = @"test.html";

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);

        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);  

        #endregion
    }

    private static void SaveHtmlFile()
    {
        var html =
        @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>This is <b>bold</b> heading</h1>
    <p>This is <u>underlined</u> paragraph</p>
    <h2>This is <i>italic</i> heading</h2>
</body>
</html> ";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        htmlDoc.Save("test.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value, you can use XPath. Example:

```
"//*[@class='Inconclusive']/div/span"
```

C# HtmlAgilityPack

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(<html code>);
var xpath = "//*[@class='Inconclusive']/div/span";
var parse = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

How to get XPath:

[image: Screenshot]

[XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)